# Is there a way to make DLLs in some folder have higher priority than app's folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, dll

Certain software I'm using comes with a broken DLL which makes it crash at random. The only way to fix issue is to download correct dll from somewhere like dll-files.com. I've already made aware developer of this, however issue was closed with "Won't fix" status.

I am also tired of copying correct dll each time I have to update that software. So I devised other solution: What if I could make just folder that has higher priority than app's folder for dll lookup (application comes with broken dll next to exe)? However I don't know how to do that.

My OS version is Windows7 x64

Comment: Simplest solution, delete the file, Windows will automatically locate the next copy.  Of course the fact this bug was assigned a "won't fix" infaictes if might not be a real issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound states, delete the DLL, but *first put the valid DLL in a known location*, either in a system folder already in the PATH, or in a new folder, in which case add the location to PATH. Depending on the DLL, you also may need to [register it with regsvr32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873).

Each time the application is updated, it will reinsert the bad DLL in its own folder, which will need to be deleted. Alternatively, *some* installers can be opened with 7-Zip, PeaZip or other tool, so you can extract only the desired files and bypass installation of redundant shortcuts etc.

Comment: Except I am tired of replacing/deleting/whatever to fix it. I want 100% "fire and forget" solution.

Comment: If you use an *installer*, then each time it's run, it will reinstall DLL's and make Registry changes. The only solution  is to *manually* extract files on update, and not all installers are user-friendly that way.